# How to get two SQL columns to echo out in two separate <td>'s side by side in PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays, foreach

I have an SQL query that selects distinct rows, counts the number of times a value is in the database then echo's out both values side by side in a HTML table in two separate 's

As a simple example.. if in the database 'John' is listed 7 times, 'Bob' is listed 3 times, and 'Jane' is listed 5 times, my HTML table should echo out as

`+------+---+
| John | 7 | 
+------+---+
| Bob  | 2 | 
+------+---+
| Jane | 5 | 
+------+---+`
'
I can get the name bit working but can't get the count to work, so instead I'm getting

`+------+---+
| John |   | 
+------+---+
| Bob  |   | 
+------+---+
| Jane |   | 
+------+---+`

Below is my actual code. All the bits regarding timestamps are working, it's just the $row['count'] bit that won't work

`//the SQL query
$query = "SELECT distinct(file_name), COUNT(file_name) AS count
                 FROM orders_thortful
                 GROUP BY file_name
                 ORDER BY file_name";`

```
//initiate array
$timestamped_array = array();

if (sqlsrv_has_rows($search)) {

    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($search, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {   

        //takes file name string from db and puts into a proper date format
        $formatted_date = date_create_from_format('d-m-Y_h-i-sa', $row['file_name']);

        //takes date and puts into a timestamp (so it can be sorted)
        $timestamp = date_timestamp_get($formatted_date);

        //put $timestamp into $timestamped_array
        $timestamped_array[] = $timestamp;

        //put $row['count'] into an array so it can be iterated through in a foreach loop
        $count_array[] = $row['count'];

} 

    //iterate through the array, putting each value in a new td
    foreach($timestamped_array as $val){

            echo "<tr>";

                echo "<td>";

                    echo $val; // this works

                echo "</td>";

                echo "<td>";

                    echo $row['count'] //this doesn't work, ays value is NULL

                echo "</td>";

            echo "</tr>";

        }
```

`}`

Comment: If you added the row counts into an array, why aren't you using it in the foreach?

Comment: ^^^ That. Note that after the `while` loop, `$row` will be `null` and enabling error display would show you that.

Comment: @ Dialex I thought I was doing so in the second <td>

Comment: I think my post will work for you but if you have all the data you want to output in the first loop why doing the second? (why not just echo in the first loop?)

Comment: I'm still newish to PHP so I never thought of this.. but after tweaking your code slightly I got this working - thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add both the time stamp and the count to the same array and then it will be simpler to iterate them.

```
$dataArray = array();
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($search, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $formatted_date = date_create_from_format('d-m-Y_h-i-sa', $row['sitma_file_name']);
    $timestamp = date_timestamp_get($formatted_date);
    $dataArray[] = array("time" => $timestamp, "count" => $row['count']); // save both timestamp and count in the array
}

foreach($dataArray as $element){
    echo "<tr><td>" . $element['time'] . "</td><td>" . $element['count'] . "</td></tr>";
}
```

Notice that in posted code you don't change anything in the timestamp or count so I think you may echo them there - but maybe you have extra code you didn't posted...